# How to read several parquet files with Type Script?

Tags: node.js, typescript, parquet

I have a folder with parquet files.

How to read them all and convert into 1 big txt file?

I am using `parquetjs` library to read 1 file:

```
(
    async () => {
        // create new ParquetReader that reads from 'fruits.parquet`
        let reader = await parquet.ParquetReader.openFile('fruits.parquet');

        // create a new cursor
        let cursor = reader.getCursor();

        // read all records from the file and print them
        let record = null;
        while (record = await cursor.next()) {
            console.log(record);
        }

    }

) ();
```

Need help with reading several files at once and combining them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert the `aynsc` function to take a `filename` parameter. Make the function return the `record`
2. Create an array of `filename`
3. Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the `filename` array into a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) array
4. Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all files to be read
5. Use [`String.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to combine all the `record`s into a one string

## Convert the `async` function to take a `filename`

Convert the `async` file to take a `filename` parameter

```
const readFile = async(filename) => {
  let reader = await parquet.ParquetReader.openFile(filename);
  let cursor = reader.getCursor();

  let record = '';
  let currentContent = '';
  while (currentContent = await cursor.next()) {
    record += currentContent;
  }

  return record;
};
```

## Read and combine all files

```
const filenames = ['f1.parquet', 'f2.parquet', 'f3.parquet'];
const readPromises = filenames.map(f => readFile(f));
const allPromises = Promise.all(readPromises);

// Read and combine
allPromises.then(contentsArray => contentsArray.join('\n'))
  .then(joinedContent => console.log(joinedContent))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks.. Getting output as `[object Object][object Object]...`